# how to get the file download url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Hi i'm wandering to make some more beautiful searcheable and reliable file list in my drive.

I make a `fileVar.getDownloadUrl()` but when i print that to the html the link is not there.
I checked with Logger.log() and the url doesn't logs.

getUrl() does work, buy i need also the download.

¿some ideas?

**code .gs**

```
function getRecFol(folId){
   var l = [];
   var fol = DriveApp.getFolderById(folId);
   var arch = fol.getFiles();

   while (arch.hasNext()){
      var a = arch.next();
      //Logger.log(a.getId());
      l.push(a.getId());    
   }// fin primera parte
   //segunda parte.
   //Logger.log(resultado);
   var fols = fol.getFolders();
   var l2 = [];
   while (fols.hasNext()){
      var a = fols.next();
      //Logger.log('folder:');
      //Logger.log(a);
      var b = getRecFol(a.getId());
   for (var i = 0;i < b.length;i++){
      l2.push(b[i]);
   }
   }
   for (var i = 0;i < l2.length;i++){
      l.push(l2[i]);
   }
// Logger.log(resultado !=[]);
   return l;
}
/* TIPO PARA EL OBJETO CON LA INFORMACION PARA EL HTML */
function listedFile(id,title,tipe,description,fold,update,vision,descarga){
   this.id = id;
   this.title = title;
   this.tipe = tipe;
   this.description = description;
   this.fold = fold;
   this.update = update;
   this.descarga = descarga;
   this.vision = vision;
}

function getData(){

   var listaF = getRecFol('IdFolder');
   var listaO = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < listaF.length ;i++){
   var f = DriveApp.getFileById(listaF[i]);
   f.getDownloadUrl();
   var o = new listedFile(listaF[i],f.getName(),f.getMimeType(),f.getDescription(),f.getParents(),f.getLastUpdated(),f.getUrl(),f.getDownloadUrl());
   Logger.log(o.description);
   listaO.push(o);  
 }
 return listaO;
   }



   function doGet(){
     return HtmlService
     .createTemplateFromFile('index')
     .evaluate();
   };
```

**html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello, world!
    <ol>
    <? var lista = getData();
    for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){ ?>
        <li>
           <a href="<?= lista[i].descarga ?>"><?= lista[i].title  ?></a> - <a href="<?= lista[i].vision ?>"> VER </a>
        </li>
        <ul>
           <li><?= lista[i].description ?></li>
        </ul>
        <? } ?>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and had a few issues with it but I finally get it to work...

It appears that `getDownloadUrl()` returns a value only for files that can actually be downloaded, ie files that are not Google documents, spreadsheets... but "normal files" (if I dare using that word) as jpg, pdf, doc and so on.

I didn't find a mention of that in the doc but maybe I didn't search very well.

Anyway, here is the simplified version of your code I used for my test, the folder I examine here containes 3 Google doc files and a jpg image and I get the downloadUrl only for the image file.

(`index.html` and `doGet()` unchanged)

```
function getRecFol(folId){
   var l = [];
   var fol = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3qSFxxxxxxxxxxU3a2VFR2M');
   var arch = fol.getFiles();

   while (arch.hasNext()){
      var a = arch.next();
//      Logger.log(a.getId());
      l.push(a.getId());    
   }// fin primera parte

   return l;
}
/* TIPO PARA EL OBJETO CON LA INFORMACION PARA EL HTML */
function listedFile(id,title,type,description,folder,update,url,download){
   this.id = id;
   this.title = title;
   this.type = type;
   this.description = description;
   this.folder = folder;
   this.update = update;
   this.url = url;
   this.download = download;
}

function getData(){

   var listaF = getRecFol('Idfolderer');
   var listaO = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < listaF.length ;i++){
   var f = DriveApp.getFileById(listaF[i]);
   var o = new listedFile(listaF[i],f.getName(),f.getMimeType(),f.getDescription(),f.getParents(),f.getLastUpdated(),f.getUrl(),f.getDownloadUrl());
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
//   Logger.log("f.getDownloadUrl() = "+f.getDownloadUrl());
   listaO.push(o);  
 }
 return listaO;
}
```

For info, here is the resulting log (a bit hard to read, I agree ^^) where we can see that only the first item has a value for the downloadUrl.
[image]

Comment: Thak you very much, now i can make in the script a condition: if there isn't a download url, use what `.getUrl()` returns. I'll update when i write it.

Comment: That would be a good solution I guess... (thx for upvote, please consider also accepting it)

Comment: my `getRecFol` function maybe is a mess but it takes not only the files within the folder, also all files in inner folders.

Comment: I simplified it for my test purpose, your original code took too long to execute for me , I didn't examine that aspect very deeply :-), it was not the point of the question here.

Answer (score 2):

For your information: there *is* a way to create a special "download as pdf" link. Use this one:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=*documentId*&exportFormat=pdf
```

It is complicated but working.